# Mi html pasado a otro ordenador se desconfigura, hasta se duplica

Tags: html, css

Mi "interfaz" nativa es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo al pasarle el código a un amigo su ventana le aparece esta interfaz:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es codigo css:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

#contendedor {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.3fr 0.7fr;
  min-height: 100vh;

}

#contenido {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("../img/Azul.jpg");
    background-size:200vh ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    border: 1px solid ;
  }
  #menbrete {
    display:block;

  }

  #resultado {

    background-image: url("../img/Gris.png");
      height: 100vh;
    }
  .imagen1 {
  position: relative;
  top:20px;
  left:21%;
  }
  .imagen3 {
    position: relative;
    top:20px;
    left: 64.5%;
  }
  .imagen4 {
    position: relative;
    top: 15%;
    border: 4px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 10px;
    }
  .imagen2{
  position: relative;
  top: 15%;
  left: 41%;
  border-radius: 100px;

  }

h1 {
  position: relative;
    top: 15%;
  font-size:300%;
  color: rgb(228, 240, 240);
  font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h2 {
  position: relative;
  top:5% ;
  font-size: 300%;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
}
h3 {
  position: relative;
  top:10% ;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
}
h4 {
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:49%;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h5 {
  position: absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:56.5%;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
}
form {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  rigth: 3%;
}



input[type="text"] {
  outline: none;
  padding: 8px;
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  border-radius: 9px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-size: 80%;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  padding: 8px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #0098cb;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 9px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es" dir="ltr">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title> Autentificacion</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/Estilo.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
<body >
      <div id="contendedor">
          <div id="acceso" >
              <div id="contenido">
                <h1>Bienvenido</h1>
                  <img src="img/Estatua.jpg" width="150" height="200" class="imagen4">
                  <form  action="index.php" method="post" >
                    <input type="text" name="codigo"  placeholder="Ingrese codigo de matricula">
                    <input type="submit" name="ingresar"  value="Ingresar">
                  </form>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div id="resultado"  >
                  <div id="menbrete">
                    <img src="img/undac.png" width="50" height="50" class="imagen1">
                    <h4>UNIVERSIDAD NACIONAL DANIEL ALCIDES CARRION</h4>
                    <h5>FACULTAD DE INGENIERIA</h5>
                    <img src="img/logoSistemas.png" width="50" height="50" class="imagen3">
                  </div>
                  <img src="img/Aceptado.png" width= "150" height="150" class="imagen2";
                  height= "250" >
                  <h2>Aceptado!</h2>
                  <h3>Lenguaje de Programacion II</h3>
                  <h3>Salcedo Victorio Michel Alexis</h3>
                  <h3>Laboratorio N°3</h3>
          </div>
      </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

El error es que al cambiar de ordenador me parece que se cambió algunas etiquetas lo que quisiera saber es que si para eso solo tendría que trabajar con el VH o porcentaje

Y quisiera saber si el css es muy largo o mucho código, y así intentar reducir en todo lo posible

Comment: sería bueno saber por ejemplo que navegador y versión ocupas en cada una de las computadoras, te invito a leer [ask], ya que con solo las imágenes poco se puede aportar

Comment: el mio es firefox quamtum 68.01 y el otro es de un colega y usa el chrome no estoy seguro de la version

Comment: te recomiendo para mejorar y asegurar que alguien te responda coloques todos los detalles necesarios, **edita** tu pregunta y ahí coloca todo lo que haga falta.

Comment: Pregunta sobre html, con etiqueta de css y sin código .... tendremos que estrenar la bola de adivinar.

Comment: dale oportunidad @JDev esperemos que haga las ediciones necesarias para mejora el contenido de la misma

Comment: @Aprendiz solo era un chiste sin maldad para que entendiera lo que falta.

Comment: A simple vista parece que no ha cargado alguna librería o algún css que utilizas. A parte de lo que te comenta Aprendiz, si es posible comprueba en el ordenador de tu compañero a ver si hay algo que no este cargando y si es así añádelo en la pregunta.

Comment: ¿el código solo tiene html como dices en la pregunta? En la url del pantallazo el archivo es php

Comment: Por favor, ¿Podrías copiar el código de las capturas y meterlo en un snippet o ponerlo como texto?  si se te hace muy difícil te ayudamos a meterlo nosotros. Solo tienes que copiarlo y pegarlo en la pregunta.

Comment: Ya puse todos los codigos gracias por su ayuda ...

Comment: @MichelAlexisSalcedoVictorio El código que has puesto se ve como debería.

Answer (score 1):

Algo no se ha debido pasar correctamente, o puede que incluso la caché, con alguna imagen o similar. En JSFiddle está correcto: https://jsfiddle.net/JGYER/yfjnp7s2/2/ (respecto a la primera imagen)